# Была получена лишняя репутация

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Доброго времени суток.

На днях зашёл на англоязычный SO, и мне так надоело вечное предложение зарегистрироваться, что решил связать с ним свою учётку ruSO. Получил на SO 100 репутации:

> Вы заработали 100 бонусных очков репутации, потому что Вы хорошо зарекомендовали себя на других сайтах сети

Я немного удивился (не знал о таком), ну и ладно. Возвращаюсь обратно на ruSO и там меня ждал очередной сюрприз - я получил +100 репы и на ruSO. Не понял. Для проверки связал аккаунт с wpSE. +100 репы дали только там. Я успокоился с проверками, но факт получения репутации на ruSO меня не очень воодушевил. На мой взгляд это чуть ли не читерски. На вопрос в чате, почему я так считаю, я дал развёрнутый ответ:

> Потому что стартовая репа = 1. Чтобы набить репу, надо принести пользу сообществу: дать хороший ответ на вопрос, задать хороший вопрос или внести одобренную правку в сообщение пользователя. И для меня лично не так уж легко было эту репу поднять. Поэтому получить 100 репы только за то, что я создал аккаунт на англоязычном SO, на котором я и сидеть-то не буду, так как не знаю англ. яз. - это больше смахивает на читерство.
>   Я подвязал туда свой акк лишь для того, чтобы пропало навязчивое сообщение, с предложением зарегистрироваться, когда я пытаюсь читать некоторые вопросы. Для меня было шоком получить за это 100 репы.
>   Вчера я набил 100 репы, согласен. Но я дал два ответа на вопросы пользователей - помог им, получается, решить их проблемы. Вот это заслуженная репа "за дело". :)

Пользователи **D-side** и **Grundy** объяснили мне, что +100 репутации дают только в том случае, когда на одном из сайтов SE 200+ репутации, а не просто за создание учётки.

Допустим это так, но всё равно не вижу в этом своей заслуги. Эта репутация для меня пользу приносит, а не для других. Да и ладно, я получил 100 репы на SO. А на ruSO зачем? Ведь 200+ репы у меня было на ruSO, а не на SO. Там у меня 101 репы были, из которых 100 - подарочные за активность на ruSO.

**PavelMayorov** предположил, что это баг (а я действительно получил 100 репы на ruSO с тем же описанием, что на SO и wpSE). А даже, если это не баг, то я не думаю, что это правильно.[image: Скриншот]

Ну как бы и всё. Я своё слово сказал, теперь решать вам, господа разработчики, что это такое и что с этим делать.

С уважением, Юрий.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не баг, так задумано, и об этом прямо написано в справке, в статье [Что такое репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

> бонус за подключение к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов: +100 для **каждого** сайта

Вы получаете бонус за линковку аккаунтов на каждом из прилинкованных сайтов.

Соответствующие топики на английской мете:

[Association bonus +100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147951/association-bonus-100?lq=1)

[Should all linked accounts get the 100 bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Страницы не прочту, уж простите, английским не владею. :) Уточнить хочу: то есть неважно сколько репутации у пользователя? Даже если 1 на ruSO, за линковку SO с единицей репы, пользователь получит +100 и там и там? А почему D-side и Grundy говорили о 200 репутации? Они ошиблись, значит?

Comment: @intro94 200 это квота, **с которой начинается** выдача этих бонусов: *"Если вы опытный пользователь сети Stack Exchange **с репутацией 200 или более** хотя бы на одном из сайтов, вы получите стартовый бонус +100 к репутации на других сайтах"* -- по первой ссылке в ответе.

Comment: @D-side вот именно - *на других сайтах*. Но откуда репутация берется *на первом сайте*?

Comment: А про это уже по второй ссылке из ответа :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov в ответе написано "для **каждого** сайта".

Comment: Похоже, что [имеет место **ошибка перевода**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). В оригинале о *других* ни слова: *"If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions"*

Comment: @D-side значит это баг?

Comment: @intro94 нет, +100 прилетит **везде**, просто у нас ошибка в справке :)

Comment: @D-side не вижу, тогда, ошибки в переводе. Почитайте перевод от [гугла](https://translate.google.ru/?hl=ru#en/ru/If%20you%20are%20an%20experienced%20Stack%20Exchange%20network%20user%20with%20200%20or%20more%20reputation%20on%20at%20least%20one%20site%2C%20you%20will%20receive%20a%20starting%20%2B100%20reputation%20bonus%20to%20get%20you%20past%20basic%20new%20user%20restrictions.%20This%20will%20happen%20automatically%20on%20all%20current%20Stack%20Exchange%20sites%20where%20you%20have%20an%20account%2C%20and%20on%20any%20other%20Stack%20Exchange%20sites%20at%20the%20time%20you%20log%20in.)

Comment: @intro94 в переводе появилось слово "других", которого в оригинале нет.

Comment: ...а вот в уведомлении, вероятно, косяк даже в оригинале :]

Comment: @D-side Уже понял. Я не понял про какое вы говорите предложение. Просто в след. предложении используется *and on any other Stack Exchange sites*. То есть слово **других** там есть. :)

Comment: @intro94 утверждение что пользователь получит репутацию на другом сайте никак не отрицает возможность получить ее на этом сайте

Comment: @intro94 это **другое** "других", которое у нас как раз переведено как надо :) *"Это произойдет автоматически **на всех текущих сайтах Stack Exchange, где у вас есть учетная запись**, и на любых **других** сайтах Stack Exchange в момент, когда вы вводите свои учетные данные."*

Comment: @PashaPash всё равно я считаю это не логичным. Как я упомянул в самом вопросе, линк аккаунта это не достижение. Я понимаю бонус на новом акке, ведь в справке написано, что это *позволит вам обойти ограничения для новых пользователей*. Но на существующем акке с, к примеру, 500 репы это зачем? Там ведь уже не новичок. :)

Comment: @D-side поэтому я и не мог понять, где ошибка. Ибо я видел только правильный перевод слова "других". :)

Comment: @intro94 отметить чужой ответ на свой вопрос как принятый - тоже не достижение. но за это же дают репутацию :)

Comment: @PashaPash Совсем забыл я про это... Хотя тут есть логическое объяснение - новичков надо стимулировать отмечать ответы. :) А эти +100 репы это уже не для новичков, а для старожилов. :)

Comment: @intro94 да, дают аж +2. точно так же - людей надо стимулировоать линковать аккаунты. вот за это и дают репутацию. Ну может еще из соображений лени - написать проверку вида (if any > 200) { all+=100 } гораздо проще, чем проверять, есть ли другой сайт с 200.

Comment: @PashaPash эта самая лень - куда более логичное объяснение для меня, как ни странно, ибо смысл от линковки теряется, когда я ни разу после этого не зайду на линкованный аккаунт. :)

Comment: Не понял. Это если обойти всю сотню (или сколько их есть?) сайтов SE, то тут (он первый где юзер зарегистрирован) ему добавят 10К репы? Или тут добавится только 100?

Comment: @avp только 100

Comment: Т.е. ТС получил тут только сотню, но написал он так путано, что я решил, что он тут получил 200 и менно это ошибка?

Comment: @avp да........

Comment: @avp уж простите, путаницы в своём вопросе я не вижу, да и скриншот прикреплён, к тому же, ясно всё показывающий. :)